# What is the shortcut to go to the parent directory when browsing a git tree with fugitive?

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I am browsing the repository state with fugitive at a particular git commit, I am able to go only into the directory, but I don't know how to go back up to the parent directory.  I end up looking this commit up again and start browsing from the top.

[image: Directory view within a tree]

What is the shortcut to go to the parent directory when browsing a git tree with fugitive?

Comment: Does `:e %:h` work? I think you can navigate just like Netrw.

Comment: @JakeGrossman Not really -- it brings me to the topmost view -- root of the tree (not one parent up).

Answer (score 0):

This is vim! It is whatever shortcut you want. I find `-` to be the most intuitive, so it works the same as NetRW.

```
nnoremap <silent> - :e %:h<CR>
```

When in a fugitive buffer, this opens the tree of the directory above the current one. When in a normal buffer, it opens the directory containing the file.